# Следует ли добавлять к каждому вопросу про Android метку Java, если это вопрос точно не по другим языкам?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, использование-метки

**Проблема:**

Часто ТС-ы не ставят [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) к вопросам по [android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). При этом вопрос не может быть решён без её участия (т.е. дело не только в [xml](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml)-разметке, косяке в [gradle](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gradle), особенностях [android-studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) etc) и нельзя сделать вывод, что вопрос по другому языку программирования.

**Вопрос:**

Таки ставить метку [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) ко всем вопросам, описанным в пред. пункте или вообще пихать её всегда, если не указан явно в вопросе другой язык, безотносительно к тому, можно ли решить проблему без [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)?

Comment: Тоже назревал такой вопрос. Но не только про `android` но например про фреймворки типа `yii, yii2` которые к `php` относятся и подобные... когда показывают `phpmyadmin` и запросы в нем,..ведь это связано также и с `mysql` с `sql`....Может это тоже как-то к вопросу присоединить?)

Comment: наверно, неплохо бы добавить ответы (отметив их общими) с возможными вариантами поведения. чтобы за них можно было голосовать.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, думаю, лучше уж сделать общий вопрос о том какие метки с какими надо рядом ставить напихать в него ссылок на отдельные вопросы по каждому случаю)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, поддерживаю, но сам не буду, т.к. определённого мнения у меня на сей счёт так и не сложилось(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил три пришедшие в голову варианта.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

надо добавлять метку [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) к вопросу про *android* только в том случае, если в вопросе речь о программе на *java*.

Comment: Не совсем согласен. Если используются специфические классы связанные с платформой андройд, ui, то метка java тут ни к чему. Чтобы ответить на такой вопрос знания по java  не помогут.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov большая часть вопросов по метке [tag:C#] - не про "стандартные" классы C#, а про что-то стороннее. Но метку C# на них все равно стаявят.

Comment: Тут речь не идет о сторонних библиотеках. Я имею в виду классы относящиеся к android api. Знания java, тут бесполезны, тут нужны познания во фреймворке. На такие вопросы должны отвечать android программисты.

Answer (score 4):

Склоняюсь к тому, чтобы ставить. Проблема может быть непосредственно связана с Java кодом и не требовать познаний в Android для ее решения.

Comment: Тут тонкая грань... Если задают вопрос типа "как в Андроид преобразовать строку в число?" то надо выпилить метку Андроид или нет? По хорошему-то андроид тут не причём, а ява - да. С другой стороны, сам я гуглю именно с `android`, т.к. такие запросы мне гугл на SO ссылки выдаёт, а если гуглить `java`, то какую-то фигню выдаёт)

Comment: Не предлагаю отрезать метку [tag:android].

Comment: Тогда ещё возникает вопрос можно ли/надо ли добавить ко всем вопросам по `java` кои, вместе с ответами можно свободно на `android` применить повесить и эту метку?..

Comment: Повесить [tag:android] на произвольный подходящий [tag:java]-вопрос? Не стоит. Иначе придется повесить и [tag:j2me] и [tag:groovy]

Comment: А почему не стоит? Как я понимаю, эти метки поисковики индексируют, и, засим, принесёт это пользу, добавив трафика и решая задачи юзеров... Правда, ограничение кол-ва меток на вопрос тут мешать будет)

Comment: Если вешать кучу меток - получается информационный шум.

Comment: Имеете в виду захламление главной или просто не одобряете множество меток под вопросами?

Comment: Не одобряю множество меток, если они избыточны. Особенно всякие там [tag:класс], [tag:цикл]...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: Тут тоже есть тонкая грань. Возможно, у андроида есть специальные методы преобразования строки в число. Пример: вопрос «как создать новый thread» в чистом C++ и в C++ с использованием Qt имею радикально разные ответы, не сводящиеся друг к другу. Поэтому [tag:android] в общем случае не является лишней меткой, даже если вопрос и имеет смысл без неё.

Comment: @VladD, т.е. вы не были бы против набега на вопросы по яве базового уровня и проставления им всем ещё и метки Андроид?.. =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: я вообще никогда не против набегов!

Answer (score 0):

Только заметил этот вопрос. Для начала, очень много вопросов именно по вёрстке и т.п, там [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) нужно выпиливать (что я и делаю по возможности).

Из части вопросов, где есть код на Java, тоже можно выпилить тег [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), так как там речь идёт о вопросах связанных с sdk. Даже если человек бы писал на [kotlin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin), то нет смысл вплетать язык, так как это, скорей всего, концептуальные вопросы. Можно в таких случаях поставить тег [android-sdk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sdk).

На самом деле, в таких вопросах очень редко бывает упор именно на Java. В большинстве случаев я бы рекомендовал выпиливать тег [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Comment: Кстати, здесь теги принято называть метками :)

Comment: @alexolut это забавно, учитывая что при вставке метки пишем всё равно `[tag:]` (:

Comment: это потому что движок не на 1С написан ;)

Answer (score -7):

да, надо добавлять метку [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) к каждому вопросу про *android*.

Comment: у Вас три разных ответа, м.б. стоит удалить некоторые ответы за ненадобностью?

Comment: это удобно для голосования. создаются **общие** ответы с разными вариантами. на мете это общепринятая практика.

Comment: теперь понятно)

Answer (score -7):

нет, надо **удалять** метку [java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), если есть метки про *android*.